# Working interactively in Python

Tags: python, matlab, interactive

Is there any way to switch to 'interactive' mode within a Python script, similar to the "keyboard" function in Matlab? I am aware of iPython, but I don't think it would allow me to 'pause' at some point in a script, e.g., within a for-loop, switch to interactive mode based on an if-statement.

In Matlab this would simply be something like:

```
for i = 1:100
    % do stuff
        if i == 55
             keyboard
        end
    % do more stuff
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the debugger.

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

This will dump you into a debug session where you can inspect and edit variables, and call functions.